# Using a service in app.config

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

So, I'm continuing my self-education in Angular...and, I've written yet more code that dosen't work, and I don't know why!

[Failing Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/THzX5/)

For this go-round, I'm writing a small front-end that I'm using to learn the Angular UI for Bootstrap datepicker system inside and out.  However, you'll notice that my two datepickers simply aren't working!

I strongly suspect that, among my problems, is how I'm invoking the `app.services.Enum` object in the `app.config`, to configure a default filter function for which days are selectable.  Pretty much, by default I'm trying to disable Sunday from being selectable, but the more specific case disables both Saturday and Sunday.

**Question**: How do I properly use my service in `app.config`?  What's more, what else am I doing wrong?

Comment: You can't inject services in a config block. Try changing `Enums` to be a constant instead. There also seems to be a few other issues with the fiddle.

Comment: @AnthonyChu If you don't mind making that an answer, I will do just that.  I didn't know you couldn't use services in a config block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't inject services in a `config` block. Try changing `Enums` to be a constant instead.

```
appServices.constant('Enums', {
    DaysOfTheWeek : {
            "Sunday": 0,
            "Monday": 1,
            "Tuesday": 2,
            "Wednesday": 3,
            "Thursday": 4,
            "Friday": 5,
            "Saturday": 6
        },
    PickerMode : {
            Day: "day",
            Year: "year",
            Month: "month"
        }
});
```